# Out of memory error in trainCascadeObjectDetector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, haar-classifier

Getting the following errors during training:

> Error using ocvTrainCascade 
>   Error in c:\temp\a3p0_3607_2384\win32\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp: Insufficient 
>   memory.
>
> Error in trainCascadeObjectDetector (line 265) 
>   ocvTrainCascade(filenameParams, trainerParams, cascadeParams, boostParams, ...
>
> Error in CascadeTrainGUI/trainDetector (line 1965) 
>   trainCascadeObjectDetector([CTS.SessionName '.xml'], ...
>
> Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: I don't understand your question, you need to include more information about your goal and what code you were running when that error occurred

Answer (score 1):

Short-term solution: try using LBP or HOG features instead of Haar. Haar features require much more memory for training than the others.

Long-term solution: use a 64-bit machine with a 64-bit operating system. Training a good object detector requires a large amount of training data, which in turn requires a large amount of memory.